# Using Proxy PAC with EWS API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exchange-server, office365api

I have a web application that calls the [EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220535(v=exchg.80).aspx) to connect to office365.

I've followed the [Get started with EWS Managed API 2.0 client applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220499(v=exchg.80).aspx) documentation on MSDN.

In the `web.config` I've specified the proxy pac:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <proxy autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="True" scriptLocation="http://example.com:8080/proxy.pac" usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
  [...]
</configuration>
```

And I try to connect to Exchange in the following way:

```
public static ExchangeService getExchangeService(String username)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;

    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(USER_365, PWD_365, DOMAIN_365);
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    //I've tried both WebProxy settings, this:
    service.WebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
    //And this (with no success):
    //service.WebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

    //I've also tried Autodiscover...
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(USER_365, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
    //...and direct url
    //service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

    service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, username);

    return service;
}
```

And the following are the method copied & pasted from MSDN:

```
private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
{
    // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
    bool result = false;

    Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

    // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
    // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
    // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
    if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(object sender,
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
    System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
    if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
    if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
    {
        if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
        {
            foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
            {
                if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                   (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                {
                    // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                    {
                        // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                        // so the method returns false.
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
        // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
        // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // In all other cases, return false.
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried to comment out the line:

```
//service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/Exchange.asmx");
```

And add the Autodiscover:

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl(username);
```

Set the proxy or not, comment out the line:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
```

But it seems that the `ExchangeService` calls directly the server without passing trough the proxy... what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove bypassonlocal attribute altogether from your proxy configuration in web.config. There is an issue with setting this attribute along with scriptLocation.

For more info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickrain/2011/03/25/why-scriptlocation-may-not-work-when-pointing-to-a-proxy-script-file-in-your-application-config-file/

Also the web.config default proxy configuration should be sufficient so you can remove any proxy setting in your code.

Maybe that's the case here.

**UPDATE**: Specifying pac script location in `proxyaddress` instead of `scriptLocation` attribute in web.config should resolve this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work... I get the same error: `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.xxx.xx.x:443`

Comment: @Alessandro have you tried setting "Use automatic configuration script" in Internet Explorer -> Internet Options -> Conncections -> Lan Settings?

Comment: Yes, I've already set that setting in "Lan Settings" and IE can't reach the 40.xxx.xx.x instead Chrome redirect me fine to `login.microsoftonline.com`

Comment: @Alessandro Is specifying proxy directly like proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" instead of scriptLocation works? If so the problem might be in a script itself.

Comment: Yes, it works... I've already seen that setting the `WebProxy` directly in the `ExchangeService` works, but I did't try to set the proxy directly in the `web.config`. Thanks... So the error should be in the pac, but I still don't understand why it works with Chrome.

Comment: It also worked with the proxy pac, but I had to use the attribute `proxyaddress` instead of `scriptLocation`. Please edit your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: oh that's very interesting, I'll update my answer. I'm glad I could help